# Switching device axes in rotation matrix for OpenGL ES2 model rotation

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, rotation, sensormanager

I'm trying to rotate a model (terrain) situated at `(X,Y,Z)=(0,0,0)` of my OpenGL-World. `+X` is east, `-Z` is north, `+Y` is altitude. View is looking to `-Y` because the device Euler angles are `(0°,0°,0°)` while the device is lying on the table pointing north.

**The Problem**:

I need to switch the axes of my device to change the measured angle `device -y` to `device z`.

Currently rotation around the `device x-axis` works (results in rotation around `World X-axis`).

But rotation around `device y` leads to a rotation around `World Y` instead of `World -Z` and rotation around `device z` to rotation around `World Z` instead of `World Y`.

By now I'm running out of ideas how to solve this. Anybody who could give me a hint please?

```
    (OpenGL)                         (Device)

   ^ +Y-axis                       ^ +z-axis                                  
   *                               *                                 
   *                               *                                 
   *                               *    ^ +y-axis (North)               
   *                               *   *                               
   *                               *  *                                
   *                               * *                                 
   ************> + X-axis          ************> +x-axis                      
  *                                                                   
 *                                                                    
v +Z-axis (Minus North)
```

**What I've tried so far:**

- Using **Euler angles** from `SensorManager.getOrientation` and switching angles works fine, though I get into gimbal lock close to pitch 90 deg. So I'm in search for another solution (the `SensorManager` rotation matrix or quaternions).
- `SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem` in almost every possible constellation -> doesn't help
- Changing cols/rows of my rotation matrix from `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix` -> doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've found a pretty easy solution using quaternions.
The axes are beeing switched at the end.

See also:

- Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763331/using-the-rotation-vector-sensor) solution
- [SensorEvent.values (--> Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values)
- [SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getQuaternionFromVector%28float[],%20float[]%29)

Now I'm still wondering how to enable pitch angles above 90 deg (in portrait mode). Any ideas?

**Activity:**

```
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor rotationSensor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  rotationSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
  ...
}

// Register/unregister SensorManager Listener at onResume()/onPause() !

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

  if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
    // Set rotation vector
    MyRenderer.setOrientationVector(event.values);
  }

}
```

**MyRenderer:**

```
float[] orientationVector = new float[3];

public void setOrientationVector (float[] vector) {

  // Rotation vector to quaternion
  float[] quat = new float[4];
  SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(quat, vector);
  // Switch quaternion from [w,x,y,z] to [x,y,z,w]
  float[] switchedQuat = new float[] {quat[1], quat[2], quat[3], quat[0]};

  // Quaternion to rotation matrix
  float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
  SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, switchedQuat);

  // Rotation matrix to orientation vector
  SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationVector);

}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
  ...
  // Rotate model matrix (note the axes beeing switched!)
  Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0,
    (float) (orientationVector[1] * 180/Math.PI), 1, 0, 0);

  Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0,
    (float) (orientationVector[0] * 180/Math.PI), 0, 1, 0);

  Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0,
    (float) (orientationVector[2] * 180/Math.PI), 0, 0, 1);
  ...
}
```